# Javascript Getting Undefined value

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(loadeddata)
console.log(loadeddata["currencyone"])
```

is printing

```
{"currencyone":"5.518720661682446","playeroptions":{"uidelay":50,"notation":"standard","notationdecimals":3,"theme":"standard","valuesinticks":true}}

undefined
```

to the console and I can not find anywhere why this is returning undefined foe the value of currencyone

Comment: You are doing the second log before that object is populated asynchronously. Without the relevant code that generates that data nobody can do much to help

Comment: Are you changing your data somewhere in the middle between both the consoles?
Or running on chrome or browser's console or anywhere in the code?